# Is it possible to debug Controller Code with Netbeans 7.0 and XDebug

Tags: php, debugging

Using any MVC Framework in PHP (say Zend Framework or CodeIgniter), is it possible to debug Controller Code meaningfully like I can debug a plain PHP script with Netbeans and XDebug.

I means whenever I start debugging it start to Step Over the Code in index.php File. Is it possible to Step-Over code during Debugging inside Controller File and simulataneously observe XDEBUG rendered Output on the Web Browser.

Because , being able to Step-Over only index.php is meaningless at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pushing F7 should help you out.

As long as you have set everything up right you should be able to "Step Into" each and every call that is done. Netbeans will open the controller file that is needed and step through it by pressing F7.

Comment: Hey Thanks , it worked ! I just had to set breakpoints in the Controller File first, and then during Debugging it automatically opened and stopped at those Files at breakpoints.

Comment: Happy to have helped you out. Did not mention the breakpoints because i thought you already had them set.